# Is it possible to save cart data client side till a user logs in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, client-side

I have to create an online shop for my final project. This is to have a cart where users can place articles even though they aren't logged on. When they log on the cart should be saved to the user.

Is it possible to save the data client side until the user logs in?

Comment: the information in the cart is probably non-trivial; wouldn't session-state be more appropriate?

Comment: well u can save it within cookies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the cart on the server side as a guest (random user GUID) until the user signs in and then convert the cart to the authenticated user. An **EXACT** sample application with tutorial answers this question perfectly. Check out the [Tutorial here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1) with the complete code here: [Mvc Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/).

P.S. To save you searching [this is the exact part](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-9) you need but I would recommend reading the whole tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

On the client side you can use cookies but it can be disabled by browser. You should combine cart with user ip ie. and store it at server side.

Comment: But how then do I delete it if the user doesn't log in?

Comment: You can add info about last call from such ip and put timeout for data. That solution allow you to keep cart between user visits - it is stronger than server side session which usually expire within 30 - 60 minutes.